# Navigating to the root/other subsites from a subsite

Tags: navigation, global-navigation

I have multiple site collections.

```
/
/sites/corporate
/sites/test
/sites/projects
```

I am looking for a way to navigate to the other site collections from each other and the root site collection.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: What you mean by navigation to other site? What I think you want....If you are login on root site collection from their clicking a link and go to other site collection, is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

You may define `New Heading` (Site Settings -> Look and Feel -> Quick Launch) with the required URL for other site collections URLs to be added to the quick launch menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SharePoint 2013 you can use Managed metadata navigation to create custom navigation for your site collections.

Read this [blog post](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/SharePoint-2013-Navigation-using-Managed-Metadata-Term-Store.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

if i get you right you want the same menu displayed on all site collections.... just like a website?

if so goto your root site collection homepage, site actions site settings -> click on navigation under look and feel -> make sure global navigation "show subsites" is checked.

Make sure it looks correct under navigation editiing and sorting. Once that is done select ok and go back to homepage. For each sub site collection under navigation you need to do the same this time under navigation you need to select "display the same navigation as the parent" under glabal navigation.

If you were to create a new site make sure you inherit the parents navigation (select yes) under navigation inheritance.

You should now see the same top bar navigation throughout all from root site to any subsite

Comment: I'm actually talking about a larger deployment, where I have multiple site collections, not just multiple sites. Top Nav bar doesn't seem to support other site collections, unless you make hard links to them